# How to create Auto Hide Tab?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on an Window application using VS 2005.
here i have a scenario where i have to create a Docked window that auto hide like our 'Solution Explorer' or 'Property Window' in VS.

I have not find that such control in VS. Please, sugges where i can find this docked control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

- [Magic Docking](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/magicdocking.aspx)

[image]

- [DockDotNET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockdotnet/)

One more to the collection.

[image]

- [DockPanel Suite](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite)

Comment: So are you still looking for help?

Comment: No, i have implemented it using "Magic Docking".

Answer (score 1):

There isn't something available within the standard windows forms. You'll have to take a look at a third party library like

- [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/windockmanager.aspx)
- [Nevron](http://www.nevron.com/Gallery.UserInterfaceFor.NET.DockingPanelsGallery.aspx)
- ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply....but i cant use the Third Party control....i want some thing that is in standard windows..Is there ant way to auto hide/show "Tab Control"?